# Multidata Type Array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation, type-conversion

Complete newbie here guys. I'm working on a Java program to prompt the user for 3 variables which are used to calculate a future investment's value. Everything works perfectly, except when it comes time to put both my datatypes into ONE array.

Here's what the output SHOULD look like:

```
Year        Future Value
1            $1093.80
2            $1196.41
3            $1308.65
...
```

This is what mine looks like:

```
Year 1
Future Value 1093.81
Year 2
Future Value 1196.41
Year 3
Future Value 1308.65
...
```

My year is an int value and my Future value is a double (rounded). I've been sitting here racking my brain and all the forums I can find and haven't been successful. Every time I put both value into an array I get an error about putting two different datatypes together. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code for my full program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class investmentValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter investment amount: $");
            double i = s.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter percentage rate: ");
            double r = s.nextDouble()/100;

            System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
            int y = s.nextInt();

            for (y=1; y<=30; y++) {
                double f = futureInvestmentValue(i,r,y);

                System.out.println("Year " + y);
                System.out.println("Future Value " + f);
            }
}

public static double futureInvestmentValue (double investmentAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, int years){
    double value=1;

    value = investmentAmount*Math.pow((1+(monthlyInterestRate/12)),(years * 12));
    double roundValue = Math.round(value*100.0)/100.0;

    return roundValue;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make your own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to start by implementing a `pad` function. Something like,

```
public static String pad(String in, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    sb.append(in);
    for (int i = in.length(); i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now we can combine that with `String.format()` to get the dollars and cents, use a consistent `printf()` for the header and output lines. To get something like,

```
// Print the header.
System.out.printf("%s %s%n", pad("Year", 12), "Future Value");
for (int y = 1; y <= 30; y++) {
    String year = pad(String.valueOf(y), 13); // <-- One more in your alignment.
    String fv = String.format("$%.2f", futureInvestmentValue(i,r,y));
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", year, fv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The System.out.println command isn't the only method available to you!

Try this in your loop:

```
System.out.print(y);  // note that we use print() instead of println()
System.out.print('\t'); // tab character to format things nicely
System.out.println(f); // ok - now ready for println() so we move to the next line
```

Naturally, you'll want to do something similar to put your headings in.

PS - I'm pretty sure this is just an output formatting question - you don't *really* want to put all these values into a single array, right?

---

Given that you really are looking for formatted output, it may be better to use the printf() method.

The following inside the loop (instead of the 3 lines I wrote above) should do the trick (untested - I haven't used printf() format strings in a long, long time).

```
System.out.printf("%i\t$%0.2f", y, f);
```

Comment: Supposing that this is really just an output formatting question, `printf` would probably be the method of choice here.

Comment: @5gon12eder my initial thinking was that he's really, really new - and better not to introduce learning the semantics of printf into the mix at this point. But, the output he's being asked to present has dollar formatting, etc... in it, so that does make sense... I'll update my answer!

Comment: This is wild, I didn't even know about printf. Unfortunately the latter code results in a failed run.

Comment: @Zeb23 ah - whoops - I didn't include the values in the call - I'll update that chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** edited to answer your question in the comments about constructors... You should also [check out this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for further understanding

You could create a class that will hold both of the arrays...
This would give you a single object, let's call it `StockData`, that holds two arrays for the two separate types you need. You need to create the object once and then insert the data separately by type.

```
class StockData {
    double[] data1;
    int[] data2;

    // default constructor
    StockData() {

    }        

    // constructor
    StockData(double[] data1, int[] data2) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }

    // getters, setters...
}
```

Then you add data to an array of its type:

```
// using default constructor to add a single value to both arrays
StockData sd = new StockData();
sd.data1[INDEX_X] = YOUR_DOUBLE;
sd.data2[INDEX_X] = YOUR_INT;

// using default constructor to add all data to both arrays
StockData sd = new StockData();
sd.data1 = YOUR_ARRAY_OF_DOUBLE;
sd.data2 = YOUR_ARRAY_OF_INTS;

// using constructor to add all array data directly
StockData sd = new StockData(YOUR_ARRAY_OF_DOUBLE, YOUR_ARRAY_OF_INTS);
```

You could also have an object that will hold the `double` and `int` value, so the object will represent a single stock information of 2 values and then create an array containing those objects...

```
class StockData {
    double data1;
    int data2;

    // default constructor same as before

    // constructor
    StockData(double data1, int data2) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }
    // getters, setters...
}

// ...
```

Adding data:

```
// create an array of StockData objects
StockData[] sd = new StockData[TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_DATA];

// ... obtain your data

// using default constructor to add a single value to the array
sd[INDEX_X] = new StockData();
sd[INDEX_X].data1 = YOUR_DOUBLE;
sd[INDEX_X].data2 = YOUR_INT;

// using constructor to add all data directly
sd[INDEX_X] = new StockData(YOUR_DOUBLE, YOUR_INT);
```

Comment: could you give me an example of the constructor that would follow? Again, still a newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A fun data structure you would be able to use here is a Map (more specifically in Java, a HashMap). What you are doing is associating one value with another, an integer to a double, so you could make something that looks like this:

```
Map<Integer, Double> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This would take the year as the integer, and the double as the price value, and you could iterate over the map to print each value.

Additionally if you really are looking for a "multidata type array," Java automatically casts from integer to double should you need to. For example:

```
int i = 2;
double[] arr = new double[2];
arr[0] = 3.14
arr[1] = i;
```

The above code is perfectly valid.

Comment: A couple of minor points: It is generally preferable to code to an interface, and diamond syntax can be used from Java 7, so your example becomes: Map<Integer, Double> myMap = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to have an specific format you could try to change your code and put this where your for is:

```
        System.out.println("Year   Future Value");
        for (y=1; y<=30; y++) {
            double f = futureInvestmentValue(i,r,y);

            System.out.print(y);
            System.out.println("      " + f);
        }
```

this way you will have your output in the format you need without using arrays. But if you want to do an array for this you could declare an array of objects and create a new object with two attributes (year and future value)

Also your class name is investmentValue and it is recommended that all classes start with upper case it should be InvestmentValue

I hope that this can help you